# Where can I download the bitcoin blockchain to do offline analysis?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, chainanalysis

Where can I download the bitcoin blockchain to do some offline analysis.

edit: Ideally I'd like to download `.txt`  (or another file extension, e.g. `.dat`, as long as the contents are unencoded and human readable) files which I could parse and analyse myself.

edit edit: I've removed a couple of (bad) examples as it confused people.

Comment: You’re not going to find a text representation because that would be many tens of terabytes. The Bitcoin client downloads all the data “unencoded”, you just have to parse it yourself.

Comment: Cool, so is the bitcoin client you mention the [bitcoin core](https://bitcoin.org/en/bitcoin-core/). I would not want to run a node, but I would like to update the data occasionally. If using bitcoin core would have access to the data and would I be able to parse it myself? I appreciate that it is a large amount of data.

Comment: Yes, you can just run the client whenever you want to update the downloaded blocks. Look at tools like bitcoin-iterate which can parse all 500 gigabytes in about half an hour on a fast machine.